# How to include a directory and your subdirectories with simplecov

Tags: ruby, simplecov

How can I add folder and subfolders of my libs to `simplecov` generate the coverage?

My `SimpleCov` Config

```
  SimpleCov.start do
    add_group 'Bot', 'app/bots'
    add_group 'Bot', 'lib/bot'
    add_group 'Controllers', 'app/controllers'
    add_group 'Models', 'app/models'
    add_group 'Helpers', 'app/helpers'
    add_group 'Libraries', 'lib'
  end
```

This is my lib tree

```
├── assets
├── bot
│   ├── base_bot_logic.rb
│   ├── bot_logic.rb
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── blacklist.rb
│   │   ├── bot_core.rb
│   │   ├── broadcast.rb
│   │   ├── emoji.rb
│   │   ├── profile.rb
│   │   ├── reply.rb
│   │   ├── setup.rb
│   │   ├── state_machine.rb
│   │   └── webview.rb
│   └── geoutils
│       └── geoutils.rb
├── estrutura.txt
├── solar
│   ├── api.rb
│   ├── assistido.rb
│   ├── atendimento.rb
│   └── validation
│       └── cpf.rb
├── solar.rb
└── tasks

7 directories, 18 files
```

But only two files are recognized by `SimpleCov`.

[image: simplevoc lib coverage]

How I can add missing folders?

**EDIT:**

I add `track_files '{app,lib}/**/*.rb'` in my SimpleCov.start and it recognize mys files, but don't calculate the coverage rate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although I missed the party, I will answer

[Getting started](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#getting-started) contains answer on your question:

> If SimpleCov starts after your application code is already loaded (via
> require), it won't be able to track your files and their coverage! The
> SimpleCov.start must be issued before any of your application code is
> required!

In this way, its **correctly**:

> require 'simplecov'
>
> require 'yourapp'

its **NOT correctly**:

> require 'yourapp'
>
> require 'simplecov'

[track_files](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/simplecov/SimpleCov/Configuration#track_files-instance_method) just includes files matched by this glob, whether or not they were explicitly required.